# How to extract the digits from string from all columns in pandas and take median of the digits?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
name,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
"Female, n (%)",1991 (38.26%),1018 (41.52%),438 (35.12%),771 (35.16%),244 (35.72%),343 (32.48%),316 (40.51%),177 (33.84%),133 (41.18%),792 (35.92%)
"Male, n (%)",3190 (61.30%),1426 (58.16%),803 (64.39%),1415 (64.52%),436 (63.84%),711 (67.33%),463 (59.36%),345 (65.97%),187 (57.89%),1403 (63.63%)
"Age, years",44.00 [38.00 - 50.00],43.00 [37.00 - 49.00],43.00 [37.00 - 49.00],44.00 [38.00 - 50.00],44.00 [39.00 - 50.00],44.00 [38.00 - 50.00],43.00 [37.00 - 49.00],45.00 [39.00 - 51.00],44.00 [37.00 - 50.00],45.00 [38.00 - 51.00]
```

What I want to do is take the median of the values but with the following criteria:

1. If the row consists of `(\d%)`, then I'd like to extract that value
2. If the row consists of `[\d - \d]`, then I'd like to extract the digits before the square bracket.

The thing to note is that each row will have the same type of data.

Expected Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Approach 1

We can `replace` the extra characters in the dataframe so that each row contains only the numerical values enclosed in parenthesis or the numerical values before the square bracket, then change the dtype of extracted values to `float` and take `median` along the columns axis

```
d = {r'.*?\((.*)%\)': r'\1', r'^(\S+)\s\[.*': r'\1'}
df['median'] = df.set_index('name').replace(d, regex=True).astype(float).median(axis=1).values
```

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/KEA3OR/1)

#### Approach 2

`stack` the dataframe to reshape then `extract` the numerical values from the stacked frame, then change the `dtype` of extracted values to `float` and calculate `median` on `level=0`

```
df['median'] = df.set_index('name').stack()\
                 .str.extract(r'((?<=\()\S+(?=%\))|^\S+(?=\s\[))', expand=False)\
                 .astype(float).median(level=0).values
```

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/vOZhEw/1)

#### Result

```
            name                      a                      b                      c                      d                      e                      f                      g                      h                      i                      j  median
0  Female, n (%)          1991 (38.26%)          1018 (41.52%)           438 (35.12%)           771 (35.16%)           244 (35.72%)           343 (32.48%)           316 (40.51%)           177 (33.84%)           133 (41.18%)           792 (35.92%)  35.820
1    Male, n (%)          3190 (61.30%)          1426 (58.16%)           803 (64.39%)          1415 (64.52%)           436 (63.84%)           711 (67.33%)           463 (59.36%)           345 (65.97%)           187 (57.89%)          1403 (63.63%)  63.735
2     Age, years  44.00 [38.00 - 50.00]  43.00 [37.00 - 49.00]  43.00 [37.00 - 49.00]  44.00 [38.00 - 50.00]  44.00 [39.00 - 50.00]  44.00 [38.00 - 50.00]  43.00 [37.00 - 49.00]  45.00 [39.00 - 51.00]  44.00 [37.00 - 50.00]  45.00 [38.00 - 51.00]  44.000
```